# How to pass session information to inappbrowser for android using javascript?

Tags: inappbrowser

inAppBrowser does not retain cache information and asks me to login again after redirection, how do I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you turn on yes on clearcache:

According to the documentation: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Clearcache: set to yes to have the browser's cookie cache cleared before the new window is opened. You should be good once you turn that off.